# Firebase and Proto causes duplicate class exception

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, protocol-buffers

I am using firebase with the following dependencies

```
implementation (platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.0'))
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx')
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx')
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx')
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx')
```

I have created a SDK which uses protobuf java. Since the firebase uses protobuf java lite. It results in duplicate class exception.

I cannot exclude protobuf from my SDK dependency because that would cause a

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3; exception.

If I exclude protobuf from firebase. It still shows duplicate class exception because of

```
com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0@aar
```

I cannot exclude this dependency, because I am afraid it would result in same NoClassDefFoundError.

Is there any way to avoid Duplicate Class Exception without any crash?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Firebase Android has migrated from depending on the old `protobuf-lite` to depend on `protobuf-javalite` ([github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1152) | [PR implementing the change](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/1534)).

I have solved this issue by adding following codes in app/build.gradle

```
android {
  ...
  configurations {
    implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-java'
  }
}
```